# do we repeat the preposition "of" after as well as between objects?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, repetition

> I thought of the puppets as well as of their doll house.
>
> I thought of the puppets as well as their doll house.

Can we omit the preposition in the second part, after as well as?

Answer (score 1):

Both example sentences are correct, although the second would be used more often for the sake of conciseness.

However, there is a third version of the sentence that is the most concise and the most common. It replaces **as well as of** in its entirety:

> I thought of the puppets **and** their doll house.

This isn't to say that there aren't stylistic reasons to use **as well as (of)** in some cases (usually to emphasize the second item as an unexpected addition to the action), but it's just not as common as the simple conjunction when the aim is basic description.

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically, they're both correct, but stylistically, the first one is tedious.   Confirmed [here](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/parallel-structure-prepositions/) at Grammarly.

Comment: I edited this to use the hyperlink as I hope you'd intended. Feel free to revise it if I did something wrong.